# No Sound on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: sound

After I installed Ubuntu 12.04, there are no sound at all on my headphone (rear jack panel).

On Sound settings > playback, it seemed that the sounds were detected after I choose 'play sound'.

Anybody can fix this issue??

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

I just did Step 1 and then reboot my laptop and the sound works.

If you are using Ubuntu 12.04 or later, then execute this command and reboot:

> **Carefully read and understand what these commands do.** For instance, **the  sudo apt-get install 
>   command includes the entire Ubuntu desktop**. This will likely create
>   **problems for users of the other flavors of Ubuntu** -- a Kubuntu user
>   would not want the Unity interface installed. While **the outcome of
>   running the suggested command string below may indeed fix certain
>   sound problems, be aware that it is a very blunt approach and could
>   result in unintended consequences.**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa;              \ 
sudo apt-get update;                                           \ 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade;                                     \ 
sudo apt-get install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils gdm \           
     ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2;        \
sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install linux-sound-base alsa-base \ 
     alsa-utils gdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r`     \     
     libasound2;                                               \ 
killall pulseaudio;                                            \  
rm -r ~/.pulse*;                                               \
sudo                                                           \ 
    usermod -aG $(                                             \
          cat /etc/group |                                     \
          grep -e '^pulse:' -e '^audio:' -e '^pulse-access:'   \
          -e '^pulse-rt:' -e '^video:' |                       \
          awk -F: '{print $1}' |                               \ 
          tr '\n' ',' |                                        \
          sed 's:,$::g'                                        \ 
    ) $(whoami)
```

Paste the whole code block into your terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>, then press enter.

Comment: thank you so much. This problem take me a long time to find solutions.

Comment: Another answerer to this question was burned by this command because they were not running default Ubuntu Unity. I've edited this post to prevent this sort of thing in the future.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
sudo killall pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Answer (score 5):

Whatever you do don't enter the huge code on the [first answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/153470/22949)! It completely ruined my login screen.

Just use `killall pulseaudio` in the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Have you been muted? For pulseaudio, try `pavucontrol`, and check if the mute button is on in the `Output Devices` tab:

[image: mute pic]

Comment: its a little wierd but i just canged the port (on the picture) and it worked!
hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I ended up plugging my speakers into the rear audio out and it worked. On the sound test under "stereo mode" the front left/right works, but when I put it in 5.1, my speakers are converted to the rear channels like they are supposed to be. So I just leave it in stereo (that's what they are anyways).

Although, if you have a laptop or "non-HD audio" hardware (only a line in, line out, mic), this won't be possible.

Also, the strange thing was my front panel audio works fine, must be something goofy with the Realtek HD audio drivers...

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue as the OP for a little while and I finally figured it out.

Check your BIOS and make sure that your onboard audio is set to Enabled. Not Auto or Disabled. Mine was on auto and nothing would make 12.04 see the device.

Answer (score 1):

This is what fixed it for me.

Open terminal

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/modprobe.conf
```

A new file will be opened, write a line below then save.

```
options snd_hda_intel model=mb5
```

Close file Reboot the computer.

Thanks to [No sound on an iMac](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135790/no-sound-on-an-imac)

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal, I ran `gstreamer-properties`, forced both input and output to *ALSA Advanced Linux Sound Architecture*, and rebooted. Then it worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

This did not work for my case Ubuntu AMD 64 12.04 with HP quad core PC 5GB ram.
Other issues existed and sound disappeared after updates and other software install. 
May have had a script bug as well?
Located odd files and delited from home page.
found that Kubuntu driver for the PC using the DVD ISO was NVidea MCP61
used sudo apt-get install Nvidea MCP61

Located synaptic files that were broken and tried to fix them.
Un installed or removed one, installed another, updated the third file.

Turned of PC and restarted after waiting for updates and upgrades to install.
The next day the sound setting are back to normal and the Dummy output setting is gone.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question as you don't say anything specific to guide the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read this: [Skype FAQ - sound system change](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10964/can-i-change-the-sound-system-used-by-skype-for-linux)

Answer (score 0):

Okey. I see your problem. I had it too. Try this. It's safe and worked for me.

Open the terminal and type

> alsamixer

Press S and select the HD-Audio Generic option. 
Scroll to automute and disable it
now turn up all the volume options 
Press Esc to exit

Done!

Now try and play something
Best of luck ;) :D