# No sound on an iMac

Tags: 12.04, sound

I have no sound on my imac, with 12.04 from a clean install from CD. I have checked alsamixer and a number of other things. Still no sound.

Comment: "a couple of other things": please elaborate - else you might say "did this already" to many suggested steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1864114

This is what I did to fix it.

Open terminal

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/modprobe.conf
```

A new file will be opened, write a line below then save.

```
options snd_hda_intel model=mb5
```

Close file
Reboot the computer.
After rebooting, speaker will show in a mute, adjust the sound preference and set "The selected device" to "Analog Stereo Output" or 'Analog Stereo Duplex'"

That was a direct quote from ubuntu forum.

Answer (score 0):

I tried for what seemed like ever to get the headphone sound to work on my iMac with 12.04 and 12.10.  Nothing worked except recently:

upgraded to Linux Kernel 3.7.3.

All is working spiffy from the headphone jack now.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

On a mac mini:

1. Sound settings
2. Output tab
3. Highlight Headphones. Adjust output volume.

Comment: This question is about an iMac. Not a Mac mini.