# How to revoke partly executed commands?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, sound

After two weeks of no-problemo ubuntuing, my sound was gone. I looked for help and found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135778/no-sound-on-ubuntu-12-04).

I entered the huge wall of code and hit "enter" and "y" a few times. While the terminal was doing it's thing I read this line in the same post: "Whatever you do don't enter the huge code on the first answer! It completely ruined my login screen." I freaked out and cancelled the operation. Now I want to revoke everything the command did, whatever it did...

And after that, I want my sound back...

[EDIT] Ok... sound is back now after nothing but a few reboots. But I'd like to know anyway because I do not know, what I did to my system.

Answer (score 0):

There's no "command roll back". If you have the commands you can undo them one at a time by just doing the reverse. But in short, keep backups, learn to read all directions before you do ANYTHING specially with root permissions (sudo) and don't blindly copy and paste commands from websites. If you don't know what it does then don't do it. Specially where sudo is concerned.