# No Sound on Saved Media Playback

Tags: apt, sound, vlc

The sound works when playing streaming videos. However, there is no sound when playing saved/downloaded videos using media player or VLC. It started after I ran `apt-get upgrade`.

The system is not muted. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on HP 14 Notebook.

Some of the things I tried.

- force reload of ALSA
- purged and reinstalled PulseAudio

I also saw a post about an issue with a desktop and here's what he did (which I also tried):

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Here's what I got:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Virtual packages like 'linux-headers' can't be removed
E: Unable to locate package uname -r

I think it's a Codec issue but I could be wrong.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Check your typing, the error message shows an incorrect spelling namely `linux-heaeders-uname -r` (heaeders)

Comment: thanks for pointing the spelling issue but it didn't resolve the problem. I'm still getting an error message when I try to run the command line

Malformed line 59 on my Sources.List

I posted another question asking how to resolve that error message. Once that's address then I can try to run this command again.

Answer (score 0):

I found this helpful thread that fixed my problem.

[No Sound on Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135778/no-sound-on-ubuntu-12-04)

I ran the code stated in the answer and it fixed the issue for videos with 720p and below. I'm still experiencing the problem for any 1080p files.